# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification incorrectly changes frame of UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I am using a `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` to know when the keyboard is shown and adjust the size of my `UIWebView` so that it isn't hidden behind the keyboard.

The strange thing is, when I change the frame in the method that gets called by `NSNotificationCenter` it changes the frame in a way that lets me scroll my `UIWebView` content (red in screenshot), but also a large portion of the `UIWebView` scrolls into view (yellow in screenshot). The yellow should never be shown.

[image]

```
- (void)keyboardWillShowOrHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

    // User Info
    NSDictionary *info = notification.userInfo;
    CGFloat duration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];
    int curve = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];
    CGRect keyboard = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification]) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:curve animations:^{
            CGRect frame = self.toolbarHolder.frame;
            frame.origin.y = (self.view.frame.size.height - keyboard.size.height) - 44;
            self.toolbarHolder.frame = frame;

            // Editor View
            CGRect editorFrame = self.editorView.frame;
            editorFrame.size.height = (self.view.frame.size.height - keyboard.size.height) - 44;
            self.editorView.frame = editorFrame;

        } completion:nil];
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:curve animations:^{
            CGRect frame = self.toolbarHolder.frame;
            frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;
            self.toolbarHolder.frame = frame;

            // Editor View
            CGRect editorFrame = self.editorView.frame;
            editorFrame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;
            self.editorView.frame = editorFrame;

        } completion:nil];
    }

}
```

If I change the `UIWebView` frame in a different method than the one called from `NSNotificationCenter`, the frame changes correctly and the area above the keyboard is only filled with my HTML content within the `UIWebView` (red).

[image]

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Hi. Can you please check the auto resizing property of your webview?

Comment: It is set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

Comment: please UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin

Comment: @jai No, sadly that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: have you figured out a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey key that returns the final expected frame for keyboard

Comment: No, I wish that fixed the issue but it doesn't. Problem persists.